# Python - Pandas - finding matches between two data frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have 2 pandas data frames, both sharing the same column names, like this:

```
    name:       dob:       role:
James Franco   1-1-1980    Actor
Cameron Diaz   4-2-1976    Actor
Jim Carey      12-1-1968   Actor
Miley Cyrus    5-23-1987   Actor


    name:       dob:       role:
50 cent       4-6-1984     Singer
lil baby      12-1-1990    Singer
ghostmane     8-10-1989    Singer
Miley Cyrus   5-23-1987    Singer
```

And say I wanted to identify individuals who share the same name and dob, and exist in both dataframes (and thus, have 2 different roles).

How can I do this?

similar to if everything existed in 1 dataframe, and I did a df.groupby(["name", "dob"]).count())

I would like to be able to identify these individuals, print them, and count the number of occurrences.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
df2=df.append(df1)#append the two dfs
dfnew=df2[df2.duplicated(subset=['name:',"dob:"], keep=False)]#keep all duplicated on the columns you wires to check
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks- that is helpful, however when I implemented like shown in your exmaple, I was simply returned a dataframe with all results from both data frames.... so just both dataframes combined.

Answer (score 0):

Well ,this will give you just the matches:

`df1.merge(df2, on=["name:","dob:",])`

output:

```
         name:       dob: role:_x role:_y
0  Miley Cyrus  5-23-1987   Actor  Singer
```

You can use an outer join to get all the results and filter them as you see fit:

`df1.merge(df2, how="outer", on=["name:","dob:",])`

Output:

```
          name:       dob: role:_x role:_y
0  James Franco   1-1-1980   Actor     NaN
1  Cameron Diaz   4-2-1976   Actor     NaN
2     Jim Carey  12-1-1968   Actor     NaN
3   Miley Cyrus  5-23-1987   Actor  Singer
4       50 cent   4-6-1984     NaN  Singer
5      lil baby  12-1-1990     NaN  Singer
6     ghostmane  8-10-1989     NaN  Singer
```